# Cocos2d-x app code not allowing volume control buttons to work on iPhone or iPad

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x

I cannot confirm whether this has been since a newer iOS version (perhaps 11 onwards) but the hardware volume buttons do not respond whilst using an app I am updating at present.
It uses `SimpleAudioEngine` and whilst I have looked at some other projects I have that use Cocos2d-x, I have tried to use the `SimpleAudioEngine` source from there, with zero success.

The version of cocos2d-x is v2.1.1

In my `HelloWorldScene.cpp` I am calling

```
`void HelloWorld::StartSoundAction()
{
    if(soundflag==0)
    {
        SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->playBackgroundMusic("background_music.mp3");
        soundflag=1;
    }
    else
    {
        SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->stopAllEffects();
        SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->playEffect("choose_your_patient3.mp3");
    }
}`
```

The music works, but I am unable to control the volume using the hardware keys on the iPhone x or the iPad Pro.

Comment: you can use  SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->setBackgroundMusicVolume(0.0f) when mute and SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->setBackgroundMusicVolume(1.0f) when full sound.

Comment: I see, but I am not able to change the volume pressing the volume up / down on the device itself?

Comment: Here you may find solution..I didn't try http://prog3.com/sbdm/blog/u010105970/article/details/40120743

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most of my apps i use the same syntax and it is working using cocos2d-x version 3.17.2.

```
CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::getInstance()->stopBackgroundMusic();
CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::getInstance()->playBackgroundMusic("background4.mp3", true);
```

[Like this one](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/flappy-fun-math-trainer/id987236624?mt=8)

But only tested on old iPhone SE hardware.